# Is it possible with concatinated data-SMS in Android?

Tags: android, sms, concatenation

Is the functionality for fragmentation and reassembling concatenated SMS messages built in for the sendsendDataMessage() and the sendTextMessage() ?

In other words; If I put a arraybyte over 200 bytes as input to the sendDataMessage, will it be fragmented and reassembled automatically, so the getUserData() will give the same 200 bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it couldn't. The maximum SMS message size is 140 bytes, even if when you use `SmsManager.sendDataMessage()`.

So you need to set a loop to handle your multipart sms. Maybe you also need `SmsManager.divideMessage(String text)` to do several fragments.

Please refer to this man's problem: http://goo.gl/vl99e

BTW, so I think just for this reason, Google choose to open this API: `SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage()`